# Decision Tree clarification : some of the trees don't display split condition

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have used multiclass data to run the Gradient Boosted Tree classifier and produced the tree result. Some of the trees don't show any condition to split the node and predicts directly. See the example below (few trees are shown):

println(gradient_boosted_tree_classifier1_model.toDebugString)

Tree 3 (weight 0.2):
    Predict: 0.07481560563940803
  Tree 4 (weight 0.2):
    If (feature 10 <= 18.7)
     Predict: 0.386736373979052
    Else (feature 10 > 18.7)
     Predict: -0.26852945052867006
  Tree 5 (weight 0.2):
    Predict: 0.05051789101360473
Same issue has been observed with Random Forest Classifier as well.

Any thoughts on the same?